Simulink Embedded Codder C-Code Compiler Error
Version: MATLAB_R2024_A
Computer: Macbook Air M2 (ARM64)
Purpose: Simulink-Program -> Embedded-Coder -> C-Code -> Error-Compiling
I've built a basic Simulink program (testing purpose) for which I generated C-Code (with main-function) using Simulinks Embedded Coder. I tried to compile the received code in Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately I get an error message and I don't really know how to fix it.
The error message:
[Running] cd "/path/CodeGenerationMontags_ert_rtw/" && gcc ert_main.c -o ert_main && "/path/CodeGenerationMontags_ert_rtw/"ert_main
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_CodeGenerationMontags_M", referenced from:
      _rt_OneStep in ert_main-50dd2d.o
      _main in ert_main-50dd2d.o
      _main in ert_main-50dd2d.o
  "_CodeGenerationMontags_initialize", referenced from:
      _main in ert_main-50dd2d.o
  "_CodeGenerationMontags_step", referenced from:
      _rt_OneStep in ert_main-50dd2d.o
  "_CodeGenerationMontags_terminate", referenced from:
      _main in ert_main-50dd2d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.471 seconds

Structure of program
What I already tried?

receiving the Code as an Zip-file (therefore all the dependencies are included, e.g. tmwtypes.h)
including libraries manually

What could be wrong?

the error indicates that the linker cannot find the symbols for the functions and variables used in my code. It should included in the compilation and linking process. Yet I do not know how to fix it..

I hope it is understandable even without the code snippets. I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.
Leopold
ert_main.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>            /* This example main program uses printf/fflush */
#include "CodeGenerationMontags.h"     /* Model header file */

/*
 * Associating rt_OneStep with a real-time clock or interrupt service routine
 * is what makes the generated code "real-time".  The function rt_OneStep is
 * always associated with the base rate of the model.  Subrates are managed
 * by the base rate from inside the generated code.  Enabling/disabling
 * interrupts and floating point context switches are target specific.  This
 * example code indicates where these should take place relative to executing
 * the generated code step function.  Overrun behavior should be tailored to
 * your application needs.  This example simply sets an error status in the
 * real-time model and returns from rt_OneStep.
 */
void rt_OneStep(void);
void rt_OneStep(void)
{
  static boolean_T OverrunFlag = false;

  /* Disable interrupts here */

  /* Check for overrun */
  if (OverrunFlag) {
    rtmSetErrorStatus(CodeGenerationMontags_M, "Overrun");
    return;
  }

  OverrunFlag = true;

  /* Save FPU context here (if necessary) */
  /* Re-enable timer or interrupt here */
  /* Set model inputs here */

  /* Step the model */
  CodeGenerationMontags_step();

  /* Get model outputs here */

  /* Indicate task complete */
  OverrunFlag = false;

  /* Disable interrupts here */
  /* Restore FPU context here (if necessary) */
  /* Enable interrupts here */
}

/*
 * The example main function illustrates what is required by your
 * application code to initialize, execute, and terminate the generated code.
 * Attaching rt_OneStep to a real-time clock is target specific. This example
 * illustrates how you do this relative to initializing the model.
 */
int_T main(int_T argc, const char *argv[])
{
  /* Unused arguments */
  (void)(argc);
  (void)(argv);

  /* Initialize model */
  CodeGenerationMontags_initialize();

  /* Simulating the model step behavior (in non real-time) to
   *  simulate model behavior at stop time.
   */
  while (rtmGetErrorStatus(CodeGenerationMontags_M) == (NULL)&&
         !rtmGetStopRequested(CodeGenerationMontags_M)) {
    rt_OneStep();
  }

  /* Terminate model */
  CodeGenerationMontags_terminate();
  return 0;
}

/*
 * File trailer for generated code.
 *
 * [EOF]
 */

CodeGenerationMontags.c:
#include "CodeGenerationMontags.h"
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#include "CodeGenerationMontags_private.h"
#include <math.h>

/* Block signals (default storage) */
B_CodeGenerationMontags_T CodeGenerationMontags_B;

/* Continuous states */
X_CodeGenerationMontags_T CodeGenerationMontags_X;

/* Disabled State Vector */
XDis_CodeGenerationMontags_T CodeGenerationMontags_XDis;

/* Real-time model */
static RT_MODEL_CodeGenerationMontag_T CodeGenerationMontags_M_;
RT_MODEL_CodeGenerationMontag_T *const CodeGenerationMontags_M =
  &CodeGenerationMontags_M_;

/*
 * This function updates continuous states using the ODE4 fixed-step
 * solver algorithm
 */
static void rt_ertODEUpdateContinuousStates(RTWSolverInfo *si )
{
  time_T t = rtsiGetT(si);
  time_T tnew = rtsiGetSolverStopTime(si);
  time_T h = rtsiGetStepSize(si);
  real_T *x = rtsiGetContStates(si);
  ODE4_IntgData *id = (ODE4_IntgData *)rtsiGetSolverData(si);
  real_T *y = id->y;
  real_T *f0 = id->f[0];
  real_T *f1 = id->f[1];
  real_T *f2 = id->f[2];
  real_T *f3 = id->f[3];
  real_T temp;
  int_T i;
  int_T nXc = 1;
  rtsiSetSimTimeStep(si,MINOR_TIME_STEP);

  /* Save the state values at time t in y, we'll use x as ynew. */
  (void) memcpy(y, x,
                (uint_T)nXc*sizeof(real_T));

  /* Assumes that rtsiSetT and ModelOutputs are up-to-date */
  /* f0 = f(t,y) */
  rtsiSetdX(si, f0);
  CodeGenerationMontags_derivatives();

  /* f1 = f(t + (h/2), y + (h/2)*f0) */
  temp = 0.5 * h;
  for (i = 0; i < nXc; i++) {
    x[i] = y[i] + (temp*f0[i]);
  }

  rtsiSetT(si, t + temp);
  rtsiSetdX(si, f1);
  CodeGenerationMontags_step();
  CodeGenerationMontags_derivatives();

  /* f2 = f(t + (h/2), y + (h/2)*f1) */
  for (i = 0; i < nXc; i++) {
    x[i] = y[i] + (temp*f1[i]);
  }

  rtsiSetdX(si, f2);
  CodeGenerationMontags_step();
  CodeGenerationMontags_derivatives();

  /* f3 = f(t + h, y + h*f2) */
  for (i = 0; i < nXc; i++) {
    x[i] = y[i] + (h*f2[i]);
  }

  rtsiSetT(si, tnew);
  rtsiSetdX(si, f3);
  CodeGenerationMontags_step();
  CodeGenerationMontags_derivatives();

  /* tnew = t + h
     ynew = y + (h/6)*(f0 + 2*f1 + 2*f2 + 2*f3) */
  temp = h / 6.0;
  for (i = 0; i < nXc; i++) {
    x[i] = y[i] + temp*(f0[i] + 2.0*f1[i] + 2.0*f2[i] + f3[i]);
  }

  rtsiSetSimTimeStep(si,MAJOR_TIME_STEP);
}

/*
 * Output and update for atomic system:
 *    '<Root>/1//RC1'
 *    '<Root>/1//RC2'
 */
void CodeGenerationMontags_uRC1(real_T rtu_u, real_T *rty_y)
{
  *rty_y = 10000.0 * rtu_u;
}

/* Model step function */
void CodeGenerationMontags_step(void)
{
  real_T rtb_y;
  real_T rtb_y_i;
  if (rtmIsMajorTimeStep(CodeGenerationMontags_M)) {
    /* set solver stop time */
    rtsiSetSolverStopTime(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
                          ((CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.clockTick0+1)*
      CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.stepSize0));
  }                                    /* end MajorTimeStep */

  /* Update absolute time of base rate at minor time step */
  if (rtmIsMinorTimeStep(CodeGenerationMontags_M)) {
    CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.t[0] = rtsiGetT
      (&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo);
  }

  /* MATLAB Function: '<Root>/1//RC1' incorporates:
   *  Integrator: '<Root>/Integrator'
   */
  CodeGenerationMontags_uRC1(CodeGenerationMontags_X.Integrator_CSTATE, &rtb_y_i);

  /* MATLAB Function: '<Root>/1//RC2' incorporates:
   *  Sin: '<Root>/U_E'
   */
  CodeGenerationMontags_uRC1(sin(31415.9265 * CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.t
    [0]), &rtb_y);

  /* Sum: '<Root>/Sum' */
  CodeGenerationMontags_B.U_Addt = rtb_y - rtb_y_i;
  if (rtmIsMajorTimeStep(CodeGenerationMontags_M)) {
    rt_ertODEUpdateContinuousStates(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo);

    /* Update absolute time for base rate */
    /* The "clockTick0" counts the number of times the code of this task has
     * been executed. The absolute time is the multiplication of "clockTick0"
     * and "Timing.stepSize0". Size of "clockTick0" ensures timer will not
     * overflow during the application lifespan selected.
     */
    ++CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.clockTick0;
    CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.t[0] = rtsiGetSolverStopTime
      (&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo);

    {
      /* Update absolute timer for sample time: [6.66671111140741E-5s, 0.0s] */
      /* The "clockTick1" counts the number of times the code of this task has
       * been executed. The resolution of this integer timer is 6.66671111140741E-5, which is the step size
       * of the task. Size of "clockTick1" ensures timer will not overflow during the
       * application lifespan selected.
       */
      CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.clockTick1++;
    }
  }                                    /* end MajorTimeStep */
}

/* Derivatives for root system: '<Root>' */
void CodeGenerationMontags_derivatives(void)
{
  XDot_CodeGenerationMontags_T *_rtXdot;
  _rtXdot = ((XDot_CodeGenerationMontags_T *) CodeGenerationMontags_M->derivs);

  /* Derivatives for Integrator: '<Root>/Integrator' */
  _rtXdot->Integrator_CSTATE = CodeGenerationMontags_B.U_Addt;
}

/* Model initialize function */
void CodeGenerationMontags_initialize(void)
{
  /* Registration code */
  {
    /* Setup solver object */
    rtsiSetSimTimeStepPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
                          &CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.simTimeStep);
    rtsiSetTPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo, &rtmGetTPtr
                (CodeGenerationMontags_M));
    rtsiSetStepSizePtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
                       &CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.stepSize0);
    rtsiSetdXPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
                 &CodeGenerationMontags_M->derivs);
    rtsiSetContStatesPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo, (real_T **)
                         &CodeGenerationMontags_M->contStates);
    rtsiSetNumContStatesPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
      &CodeGenerationMontags_M->Sizes.numContStates);
    rtsiSetNumPeriodicContStatesPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
      &CodeGenerationMontags_M->Sizes.numPeriodicContStates);
    rtsiSetPeriodicContStateIndicesPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
      &CodeGenerationMontags_M->periodicContStateIndices);
    rtsiSetPeriodicContStateRangesPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
      &CodeGenerationMontags_M->periodicContStateRanges);
    rtsiSetContStateDisabledPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo, (boolean_T**)
      &CodeGenerationMontags_M->contStateDisabled);
    rtsiSetErrorStatusPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
                          (&rtmGetErrorStatus(CodeGenerationMontags_M)));
    rtsiSetRTModelPtr(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
                      CodeGenerationMontags_M);
  }

  rtsiSetSimTimeStep(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo, MAJOR_TIME_STEP);
  rtsiSetIsMinorTimeStepWithModeChange(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,
    false);
  rtsiSetIsContModeFrozen(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo, false);
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->intgData.y = CodeGenerationMontags_M->odeY;
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->intgData.f[0] = CodeGenerationMontags_M->odeF[0];
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->intgData.f[1] = CodeGenerationMontags_M->odeF[1];
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->intgData.f[2] = CodeGenerationMontags_M->odeF[2];
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->intgData.f[3] = CodeGenerationMontags_M->odeF[3];
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->contStates = ((X_CodeGenerationMontags_T *)
    &CodeGenerationMontags_X);
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->contStateDisabled = ((XDis_CodeGenerationMontags_T *)
    &CodeGenerationMontags_XDis);
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.tStart = (0.0);
  rtsiSetSolverData(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo, (void *)
                    &CodeGenerationMontags_M->intgData);
  rtsiSetSolverName(&CodeGenerationMontags_M->solverInfo,"ode4");
  rtmSetTPtr(CodeGenerationMontags_M, &CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.tArray[0]);
  CodeGenerationMontags_M->Timing.stepSize0 = 6.66671111140741E-5;

  /* InitializeConditions for Integrator: '<Root>/Integrator' */
  CodeGenerationMontags_X.Integrator_CSTATE = 0.0;
}

/* Model terminate function */
void CodeGenerationMontags_terminate(void)
{
  /* (no terminate code required) */
}

/*
 * File trailer for generated code.
 *
 * [EOF]
 */

CodeGenerationMontags.h:
#ifndef CodeGenerationMontags_h_
#define CodeGenerationMontags_h_
#ifndef CodeGenerationMontags_COMMON_INCLUDES_
#define CodeGenerationMontags_COMMON_INCLUDES_
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#include "rtw_continuous.h"
#include "rtw_solver.h"
#include "math.h"
#endif                              /* CodeGenerationMontags_COMMON_INCLUDES_ */

#include "CodeGenerationMontags_types.h"
#include <string.h>

/* Macros for accessing real-time model data structure */
#ifndef rtmGetErrorStatus
#define rtmGetErrorStatus(rtm)         ((rtm)->errorStatus)
#endif

#ifndef rtmSetErrorStatus
#define rtmSetErrorStatus(rtm, val)    ((rtm)->errorStatus = (val))
#endif

#ifndef rtmGetStopRequested
#define rtmGetStopRequested(rtm)       ((rtm)->Timing.stopRequestedFlag)
#endif

#ifndef rtmSetStopRequested
#define rtmSetStopRequested(rtm, val)  ((rtm)->Timing.stopRequestedFlag = (val))
#endif

#ifndef rtmGetStopRequestedPtr
#define rtmGetStopRequestedPtr(rtm)    (&((rtm)->Timing.stopRequestedFlag))
#endif

#ifndef rtmGetT
#define rtmGetT(rtm)                   (rtmGetTPtr((rtm))[0])
#endif

#ifndef rtmGetTPtr
#define rtmGetTPtr(rtm)                ((rtm)->Timing.t)
#endif

#ifndef rtmGetTStart
#define rtmGetTStart(rtm)              ((rtm)->Timing.tStart)
#endif

/* Block signals (default storage) */
typedef struct {
  real_T U_Addt;                       /* '<Root>/Sum' */
} B_CodeGenerationMontags_T;

/* Continuous states (default storage) */
typedef struct {
  real_T Integrator_CSTATE;            /* '<Root>/Integrator' */
} X_CodeGenerationMontags_T;

/* State derivatives (default storage) */
typedef struct {
  real_T Integrator_CSTATE;            /* '<Root>/Integrator' */
} XDot_CodeGenerationMontags_T;

/* State disabled  */
typedef struct {
  boolean_T Integrator_CSTATE;         /* '<Root>/Integrator' */
} XDis_CodeGenerationMontags_T;

#ifndef ODE4_INTG
#define ODE4_INTG

/* ODE4 Integration Data */
typedef struct {
  real_T *y;                           /* output */
  real_T *f[4];                        /* derivatives */
} ODE4_IntgData;

#endif

/* Real-time Model Data Structure */
struct tag_RTM_CodeGenerationMontags_T {
  const char_T *errorStatus;
  RTWSolverInfo solverInfo;
  X_CodeGenerationMontags_T *contStates;
  int_T *periodicContStateIndices;
  real_T *periodicContStateRanges;
  real_T *derivs;
  XDis_CodeGenerationMontags_T *contStateDisabled;
  boolean_T zCCacheNeedsReset;
  boolean_T derivCacheNeedsReset;
  boolean_T CTOutputIncnstWithState;
  real_T odeY[1];
  real_T odeF[4][1];
  ODE4_IntgData intgData;

  /*
   * Sizes:
   * The following substructure contains sizes information
   * for many of the model attributes such as inputs, outputs,
   * dwork, sample times, etc.
   */
  struct {
    int_T numContStates;
    int_T numPeriodicContStates;
    int_T numSampTimes;
  } Sizes;

  /*
   * Timing:
   * The following substructure contains information regarding
   * the timing information for the model.
   */
  struct {
    uint32_T clockTick0;
    time_T stepSize0;
    uint32_T clockTick1;
    time_T tStart;
    SimTimeStep simTimeStep;
    boolean_T stopRequestedFlag;
    time_T *t;
    time_T tArray[2];
  } Timing;
};

/* Block signals (default storage) */
extern B_CodeGenerationMontags_T CodeGenerationMontags_B;

/* Continuous states (default storage) */
extern X_CodeGenerationMontags_T CodeGenerationMontags_X;

/* Disabled states (default storage) */
extern XDis_CodeGenerationMontags_T CodeGenerationMontags_XDis;

/* Model entry point functions */
extern void CodeGenerationMontags_initialize(void);
extern void CodeGenerationMontags_step(void);
extern void CodeGenerationMontags_terminate(void);

/* Real-time Model object */
extern RT_MODEL_CodeGenerationMontag_T *const CodeGenerationMontags_M;

/*-
 * These blocks were eliminated from the model due to optimizations:
 *
 * Block '<Root>/Display' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<S3>/Data Type Duplicate' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<S3>/MinMax' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<S4>/FixPt Data Type Duplicate2' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<S4>/Initial Condition' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<S4>/Memory' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<S4>/Reset' : Unused code path elimination
 * Block '<Root>/Scope' : Unused code path elimination
 */

/*-
 * The generated code includes comments that allow you to trace directly
 * back to the appropriate location in the model.  The basic format
 * is <system>/block_name, where system is the system number (uniquely
 * assigned by Simulink) and block_name is the name of the block.
 *
 * Use the MATLAB hilite_system command to trace the generated code back
 * to the model.  For example,
 *
 * hilite_system('<S3>')    - opens system 3
 * hilite_system('<S3>/Kp') - opens and selects block Kp which resides in S3
 *
 * Here is the system hierarchy for this model
 *
 * '<Root>' : 'CodeGenerationMontags'
 * '<S1>'   : 'CodeGenerationMontags/1//RC1'
 * '<S2>'   : 'CodeGenerationMontags/1//RC2'
 * '<S3>'   : 'CodeGenerationMontags/MinMax Running Resettable'
 * '<S4>'   : 'CodeGenerationMontags/MinMax Running Resettable/Subsystem'
 */
#endif                                 /* CodeGenerationMontags_h_ */

/*
 * File trailer for generated code.
 *
 * [EOF]
 */

CodeGenerationMontags_private.h:
#ifndef CodeGenerationMontags_private_h_
#define CodeGenerationMontags_private_h_
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#include "CodeGenerationMontags_types.h"
#include "CodeGenerationMontags.h"
#include "rtw_continuous.h"
#include "rtw_solver.h"

/* Private macros used by the generated code to access rtModel */
#ifndef rtmIsMajorTimeStep
#define rtmIsMajorTimeStep(rtm)        (((rtm)->Timing.simTimeStep) == MAJOR_TIME_STEP)
#endif

#ifndef rtmIsMinorTimeStep
#define rtmIsMinorTimeStep(rtm)        (((rtm)->Timing.simTimeStep) == MINOR_TIME_STEP)
#endif

#ifndef rtmSetTPtr
#define rtmSetTPtr(rtm, val)           ((rtm)->Timing.t = (val))
#endif

extern void CodeGenerationMontags_uRC1(real_T rtu_u, real_T *rty_y);

/* private model entry point functions */
extern void CodeGenerationMontags_derivatives(void);

#endif                                 /* CodeGenerationMontags_private_h_ */

/*
 * File trailer for generated code.
 *
 * [EOF]
 */

CodeGenerationMontags_types.h:
#ifndef CodeGenerationMontags_types_h_
#define CodeGenerationMontags_types_h_

/* Forward declaration for rtModel */
typedef struct tag_RTM_CodeGenerationMontags_T RT_MODEL_CodeGenerationMontag_T;

#endif                                 /* CodeGenerationMontags_types_h_ */

rtw_continous.h:
#ifndef RTW_CONTINUOUS_H__
#define RTW_CONTINUOUS_H__

#ifdef MATLAB_MEX_FILE
#include "tmwtypes.h"
#else
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#endif

/* For models registering MassMatrix */
typedef enum {
    SS_MATRIX_NONE,
    SS_MATRIX_CONSTANT,
    SS_MATRIX_TIMEDEP,
    SS_MATRIX_STATEDEP
} ssMatrixType;

typedef enum {
    SOLVER_MODE_AUTO, /* only occurs in
                         mdlInitializeSizes/mdlInitializeSampleTimes */
    SOLVER_MODE_SINGLETASKING,
    SOLVER_MODE_MULTITASKING
} SolverMode;

typedef enum { MINOR_TIME_STEP, MAJOR_TIME_STEP } SimTimeStep;

/* =============================================================================
 * Model methods object
 * =============================================================================
 */
typedef void (*rtMdlInitializeSizesFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlInitializeSampleTimesFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlStartFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlOutputsFcn)(void* rtModel, int_T tid);
typedef void (*rtMdlUpdateFcn)(void* rtModel, int_T tid);
typedef void (*rtMdlDerivativesFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlProjectionFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlMassMatrixFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlForcingFunctionFcn)(void* rtModel);
typedef void (*rtMdlTerminateFcn)(void* rtModel);
#ifdef RT_MALLOC
typedef real_T (*rtMdlDiscreteEventsFcn)(void* pModel,
                                         int_T rtmNumSampTimes,
                                         void* rtmTimingData,
                                         int_T* rtmSampleHitPtr,
                                         int_T* rtmPerTaskSampleHits);
#endif

typedef struct _RTWRTModelMethodsInfo_tag {
    void* rtModelPtr;
    rtMdlInitializeSizesFcn rtmInitSizesFcn;
    rtMdlInitializeSampleTimesFcn rtmInitSampTimesFcn;
    rtMdlStartFcn rtmStartFcn;
    rtMdlOutputsFcn rtmOutputsFcn;
    rtMdlUpdateFcn rtmUpdateFcn;
    rtMdlDerivativesFcn rtmDervisFcn;
    rtMdlProjectionFcn rtmProjectionFcn;
    rtMdlMassMatrixFcn rtmMassMatrixFcn;
    rtMdlForcingFunctionFcn rtmForcingFunctionFcn;
    rtMdlTerminateFcn rtmTerminateFcn;
#ifdef RT_MALLOC
    rtMdlDiscreteEventsFcn rtmDiscreteEventsFcn;
#endif
} RTWRTModelMethodsInfo;

#define rtmiSetRTModelPtr(M, rtmp) ((M).rtModelPtr = (rtmp))
#define rtmiGetRTModelPtr(M) (M).rtModelPtr

#define rtmiSetInitSizesFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmInitSizesFcn = ((rtMdlInitializeSizesFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetInitSampTimesFcn(M, fp) \
    ((M).rtmInitSampTimesFcn = ((rtMdlInitializeSampleTimesFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetStartFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmStartFcn = ((rtMdlStartFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetOutputsFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmOutputsFcn = ((rtMdlOutputsFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetUpdateFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmUpdateFcn = ((rtMdlUpdateFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetDervisFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmDervisFcn = ((rtMdlDerivativesFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetProjectionFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmProjectionFcn = ((rtMdlProjectionFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetMassMatrixFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmMassMatrixFcn = ((rtMdlMassMatrixFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetForcingFunctionFcn(M, fp) \
    ((M).rtmForcingFunctionFcn = ((rtMdlForcingFunctionFcn)(fp)))
#define rtmiSetTerminateFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmTerminateFcn = ((rtMdlTerminateFcn)(fp)))
#ifdef RT_MALLOC
#define rtmiSetDiscreteEventsFcn(M, fp) ((M).rtmDiscreteEventsFcn = ((rtMdlDiscreteEventsFcn)(fp)))
#endif

#define rtmiInitializeSizes(M) ((*(M).rtmInitSizesFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiInitializeSampleTimes(M) ((*(M).rtmInitSampTimesFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiStart(M) ((*(M).rtmStartFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiOutputs(M, tid) ((*(M).rtmOutputsFcn)((M).rtModelPtr, tid))
#define rtmiUpdate(M, tid) ((*(M).rtmUpdateFcn)((M).rtModelPtr, tid))
#define rtmiDerivatives(M) ((*(M).rtmDervisFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiProjection(M) ((*(M).rtmProjectionFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiMassMatrix(M) ((*(M).rtmMassMatrixFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiForcingFunction(M) ((*(M).rtmForcingFunctionFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#define rtmiTerminate(M) ((*(M).rtmTerminateFcn)((M).rtModelPtr))
#ifdef RT_MALLOC
#define rtmiDiscreteEvents(M, x1, x2, x3, x4) \
    ((*(M).rtmDiscreteEventsFcn)((M).rtModelPtr, (x1), (x2), (x3), (x4)))
#endif
#endif /* __RTW_CONTINUOUS_H__ */


Please [edit] your question and include a [mre] as text, formatted as a code block instead of showing a screenshot. What exactly do you mean with "including libraries manually"? You seem to compile a single file ert_main.c to a binary ert_main instead of linking the objects of both .c files. I don't know if you would have to link a library as well. I cannot give any specific help for Visual Studio Code or compiling code generated from Simulink.

Unfortunately I've exceeded the limit. rtw_solver.h and rtwtypes.h are missing. It is difficult to give an minimal reprocuible example with auto generated code. Hopefully this helps to understand my issue! :/

With "including libraries manually" I mean that I initially had the problem with the generated code that certain libraries were not integrated. For example rtwtypes.h was missing in the directory. I then moved these into the correct directory by hand.

All requested information should be added to the question. rtwtypes.h is not a library, but a header file. A library would usually be named .a, .so, .lib or .dll. I still think that the main problem is that you don't link the objects of all .c files and maybe libraries (if required). How do you get to this command: gcc ert_main.c -o ert_main? Why don't you use something like gcc ert_main.c CodeGenerationMontags.c -o ert_main or separate compile commands for all .c files followed by a command to link all object files?

gcc ert_main.c CodeGenerationMontags.c -o ert_main worked for me! Probably something went wrong with my linker/settings. Thank you so much :)
I received gcc ert_main.c -o ert_main just by pressing "run" in Visual Studio Code.
